Why does my android vector icon appear slightly outside of the imageView box?
I have this svg:
<vector android:height="14dp" android:viewportHeight="16"
    android:viewportWidth="16" android:width="14dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#ffffff" android:pathData="M8.97,5.44H7V4H8.97V5.44Z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#ffffff" android:pathData="M8.943,12H7.053V6.38H8.943V12Z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#ffffff" android:fillType="evenOdd" android:pathData="M8,16C12.418,16 16,12.418 16,8C16,3.582 12.418,0 8,0C3.582,0 0,3.582 0,8C0,12.418 3.582,16 8,16ZM8,14.5C11.59,14.5 14.5,11.59 14.5,8C14.5,4.41 11.59,1.5 8,1.5C4.41,1.5 1.5,4.41 1.5,8C1.5,11.59 4.41,14.5 8,14.5Z"/>
</vector>

Now, i am trying to put some text and then this icon in an Image view. Here is how to reproduce the problem, simply put this to the layout in android studio and observe the preview. The info icon does not appear vertically centered!
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ad_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Ad Info"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ads_info" />

</LinearLayout>


For the life of me, I cannot get the image view to center vertically.
It appears that icon itself went slightly above the imageview verticle box. Does anyone know what is wrong with my image view?
Is this a problem with the SVG icon itself?

